# Laravel 5.3 str_replace on username before login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a login form which uses a phone number instead of the default email to authenticate a user.

Normally, this would work fine, but because I formatted the number in the input field for user convenience in order to make it easier to read , it is being sent with white spaces.

***Example***

The number I send from the form: 18 23 23 54

What it's like in the database: 18232354

Therefore I need to remove the white spaces.

**What I have (LoginController.php):**

```
public function username() {
    return "number";
}
```

**What I want (LoginController.php):**

```
public function username() {
    return (int)str_replace(" ","",$number);
}
```

Obviously the above is not possible, it is just to show the desired outcome.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `str_replace(" ","",$number);` is fine to remove white space

Comment: I'd warn against treating a phone number as an actual number.  Numerical formats should be used for things that you want to perform mathematical operations on or for efficiency of storage. Phone numbers should definitely be sanitised before storing as a username, but consider brackets, international dialling codes, internal extensions, in addition to the removal of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This will return `$number` without whitespaces:

```
public function username() {
     return str_replace(" ","",$number);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the issue with using a `$variable` is that it's not defined. I need to somehow catch the variable.

It throws this error: `ErrorException: Undefined variable: number`

I assume I need something like:
`public function username(Request $request) {
     return str_replace(" ","",$request->number);
}`

I tried the above but it does not catch the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to strip all non-digit characters. If, for example, in the future you would like to format the number with `-`, like `18-23-23-54`. So your code could be:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/g", "", $number);
```

Comment: Yes, but then `$number` is undefined. I need to somehow catch the variable (look at the comment above)